# How to use setOnClickListener on menu icon

Tags: java, android

How to use the set on click listener functionality for the menu icon(delete). I have delete icon in menu. By using that I want to delete the selected event.

For that task i have to use setOnClickListener.

I had tried with item selected for that delete icon in menu.it is not working properly.so i don't want to use that method. I want to try this in set on click listener.

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
// int Id = item.getItemId();
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.menu_cancel_event:
            del();
            eventMO.setIsDelete(1);
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
   private void del(){

        SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        final long Id=eventMO.getEventId();
        db.delete("event", "Event_ID" + " = ?", new String[] {String.valueOf(Id)});
        db.close();
}
```

Comment: What is not working? Can you be specific?

Comment: In update event after clicking delete icon ,i want to click save button also...i don't want that.That is why i am saying that is not working properly....what is my need is after clicking that delete icon i should go back to event list i don't want to click any other button

Comment: Can you move this comment to your question. and Also, I would like to see what you want to achieve, Because this is best way to handle the item click events. If you tell me exactly what this **In update event after clicking delete icon ,i want to click save button also** means, I can give you a precise answer.

Comment: I had created a events by using create occasion window.created events will be in a event dashboard.By clicking the particular event in an event list i can update that event.I can delete that event also.while clicking the event to update,it will goes to create window,where i can edit that.To update that event i will give save button after the existing event is changed.To delete the particular event also i should click that event ,it will goes to create occasion tab,where i have delete icon in menu.

Comment: By this i can delete that event from the event list.After clicking that delete icon it should delete the event and go back to the event list dashboard..What is my problem is by using the above code.i selected the particular event to delete,it goes to create occasion after click that delete icon i should click save button also(which is used to create or update the event)..it is not going back to event dashboard after click the delete icon.it is still in create occasion window after clicking save only it backs to event list .i want after click delete icon it directly goes to event dashboard

Comment: I hope you resolved the issue. (y)

Comment: No..not yet ...i need help

Comment: Now i want to trigger the save button... btn_create_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {    this is my click listener for save button....i want to trigger this save button in my options item selected,by this i can get my expected output(i think so)....i don't know how to trigger this btn_create_button(for save)...it will programmatically click that save button and i will get expected result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do like this... I hope you create a close image icon on your custom Layout. which you are inflating your all data. In my case if User hold for few seconds then that icon will be visible and if use r select that close icon then it will deleted from database.. code is here

```
holder.album_img.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            holder.rmv_img.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            return true;
        }
    });
```

**And When you click the delete icon  code is here**

```
    holder.rmv_img.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    dbHelper = new DBHelper(context);
                    try {
                        SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
                        db.delete(User_Detail.TABLE_4, User_Detail.KEY_ID_ALBUM_IMAGE + " ='" + img_list.get(position).getId_() + "'", null);
                        img_list.remove(position);
                        notifyDataSetChanged();
                        popupWindow.dismiss();
                        holder.rmv_img.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            });
```

Modify according you... Happy Coding :-)

Comment: Thank you...here rmv_img is icon name.What is holder..i need to import some package for that correct.Because it shows an error in holder

Comment: basically , this is adapter claas, in which we use ViewHolder class... so holder is instance of ViewHolder claas.. if we are doing any update or delet from database then we should perform this action in Adapter claas.

Comment: Thank you for your response

Answer (score 0):

You have to override method `onOptionsItemsSelect(MenuItem item)`

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onOptionsItemSelected%28android.view.MenuItem%29

Comment: Thank you for your response